# Mirroring GitHub pages from master branch - master branch not updating

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I wanted to mirror my GitHub pages branch to match the master branch, so that whenever I push to `origin master`, the `gh-pages` branch gets automatically synched and pushed as well.

I followed a tutorial on how to do this, and it seems that now whenever I do a push from my master branch, only the gh-pages branch is getting updated.

I removed the local and remote gh-pages branch,

```
git branch -D gh-pages        # delete local
git push -u origin :gh-pages  # delete remote
```

and then tried to *pull* from my master branch, but get the following error:

```
> git checkout master
> git pull
> Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'refs/heads/gh-pages'
from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.
```

If I *push* my master branch, it re-creates the gh-pages remote branch, but does not update the master branch...

In my git config file:

```
> git config -l
credential.helper=osxkeychain
user.name=Kyle
user.email=kyle@email.com
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
core.precomposeunicode=true
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/kylesb/range.js.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
remote.origin.push=+refs/heads/master:refs/heads/gh-pages
remote.origin.push=+refs/heads/master:refs/heads/gh-pages
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/gh-pages
```

How can I fix this?

---

Update:

I was able to fix this simply by editing the .git/config file, and resetting it to the following original content:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/<username>/<repository_name>.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "gh-pages"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/gh-pages
```

Now I just have to push my `gh-pages` branch manually, and everything is fine:

```
> git checkout gh-pages
> git merge master
> git push -u origin gh-pages
```

Comment: You should post that as an answer instead of an edit. It fits the Q&A format of the site a bit better. (Answering your own question is definitely allowed, and even encouraged.)

Answer (score 0):

gh-pages is set as the default branch to attempt to merge with master, but it no longer exists.

Unset master's merge branch with `git config --unset branch.master.merge`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you are using git less the version 2 upgrade it if you can since up to version 2 each pull.push used to push **All** the changed branches to the remote, even the ones you did not want to push.

---

Here is the git v2.0 release notes which explain the change in the way git treat push (simple vs matching).

> ## Git v2.0 Release Notes
>
> ### Backward compatibility notes
>
> When `git push [$there]` does not say what to push, we have used the
>   traditional **`matching`** semantics so far (all your branches were sent
>   to the remote as long as there already are branches of the same name
>   over there).  In Git 2.0, the default is now the `simple` semantics,
>   which pushes:
>
> - only the current branch to the branch with the same name, and only
>     when the current branch is set to integrate with that remote
>     branch, if you are pushing to the same remote as you fetch from; or
> - only the current branch to the branch with the same name, if you
>     are pushing to a remote that is not where you usually fetch from.
>
> You can use the configuration variable `push.default` to change
>   this.  If you are an old-timer who wants to keep using the
>   `matching` semantics, you can set the variable to `matching`, for
>   example.  Read the documentation for other possibilities.

---

To answer your question.

By default you can push to the remote the branch you are currently on.
Since you try to push a different branch name you should not do it when you are on the `master` branch.
Checkout a new gh-pages and then push to remote

```
# start from current master
git checkout master

# Checkout teh new gh-pages branch
git checkout -b gh-pages

# do a force push instead of deleting the branch
# the force will override and prevoius commits
git push -f gh-pages
```